# Calling a C, C++ program from Java

Tags: java, c++, c

Is it possible to call C or C++ code from a Java Code, i can re-write the code in Java, but need to reuse the existing code..

Thanks

Comment: I would go with JNA. It's built on JNI but quite a bit easier to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible using the [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

Answer (score 5):

I'd say that JNA or Java Native Access is easier to use. It's built on JNI, but there's no need to create a header file. Instead just call from the dll: [Java Native Access](http://jna.java.net/)